# How to make an object subscriptable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

In Python I can make an object subscriptable by implementing the `__getitem__` method in a class:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, furniture):
        self.furniture = furniture

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.furniture[index]

furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed'] 
room = Room(furniture)
print(room[1]) # prints TV
```

As a result I can retrieve an item by only providing an index.

Can I achieve the same in Javascript? Currently I need to call the `getitem` method explicitly:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(furniture) {
    this.furniture = furniture
  }

  getitem(index) {
    return this.furniture[index]
  }
}

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed']
let room = new Room(furniture)
console.log(room.getitem(1))
```

Comment: Do you expect to be able to call `room[1]` and get `"TV"` back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define index properties from your array as part of your object instance. You can do this for each item in your `furniture` array like so:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(furniture) {
    this.furniture = furniture;
    
    for(const [idx, item] of this.furniture.entries()) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, idx, {
        value: item
      });
    }
  }
}

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed']
let room = new Room(furniture);
console.log(room[0]); // chair
console.log(room[1]); // TV
console.log(room[2]); // bed
```

The above method allows you to configure what you want each index to return explicitly. You can also further customize it by adding properties such as `writeable` if you want to be able to set values at particular indexes. Alternatively, you could also extend the `Array` class which does much of this for you, as well as provides you with the array prototype's methods:

```js
class Room extends Array {
  constructor(furniture) {
    super(...furniture);
    this.furniture = furniture;
  }
}

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed']
let room = new Room(furniture);
console.log(room[0]); // chair
console.log(room[1]); // TV
console.log(room[2]); // bed

room[1] = "table";
console.log(room[1]);
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that you won't get new properties as entries get added or get properties removed as any `furniture` items are dropped.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, perhaps you could add an additional method to the class which would take an array of new furniture items to update indexes...

Comment: Either add an `updateFurniture` method or `addFurniture`/`removeFurniture` methods that change the array and update the indeces. Although extending the Array class is also pretty simple way to implement it. As long as it makes sense to have the Array functionality added to this, it's a neat solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to dynamically access numeric properties from the array, you can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for your objects with the [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) to intercept calls to numeric properties and redirect them to the `getitem` method:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(furniture) {
    this.furniture = furniture
  }

  getitem(index) {
    return this.furniture[index]
  }
}

const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    const numericProp = Number(prop);
    
    //verify the property is actually an integer
    if (Number.isInteger(numericProp)) {
      return target.getitem(numericProp);
    } else {
      //return what would be normally returned
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
  }
}

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed']
let room = new Room(furniture)

const proxy = new Proxy(room, handler);
console.log(proxy[0]);// chair
console.log(proxy[1]);// TV
console.log(proxy[2]);// bed
console.log(proxy[3]);// undefined

room.furniture.push("table");

console.log(proxy[3]);// table

console.log(proxy.furniture); //["chair", "TV", "bed", "table"]
```

You can also use the [`construct` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) to intercept the `new` keyword and return already proxied objects:

```js
class Room {
  constructor(furniture) {
    this.furniture = furniture
  }

  getitem(index) {
    return this.furniture[index]
  }
}

const numericGetHandler = {
  get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
    const numericProp = Number(prop);
    
    //verify the property is actually an integer
    if (Number.isInteger(numericProp)) {
      return target.getitem(numericProp);
    } else {
      //return what would be normally returned
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
  }
}

const constructProxyHandler = {
  construct(target, args) {
    //call the constructor normally
    const instance = new target(...args);
    
    //return a proxy
    return new Proxy(instance, numericGetHandler);
  }
};

const ProxyRoom = new Proxy(Room, constructProxyHandler);

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed']
let room = new ProxyRoom(furniture)

console.log(room instanceof Room); //true

console.log(room[0]);// chair
console.log(room[1]);// TV
console.log(room[2]);// bed
console.log(room[3]);// undefined

room.furniture.push("table");

console.log(room[3]);// table

console.log(room.furniture); //["chair", "TV", "bed", "table"]
```

Since the Proxy is essentially transparent, if you're using modules, you can just do `export new Proxy(Room, constructProxyHandler)` and thus when importing, you don't need to know nor care that Proxies are involved. You can just `import Room from 'room.js'` and treat `Room` as normal.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply access any property of a JavaScript array by design. There is no need to define specific getters or setters for this purpose.

```js
class Room {
  constructor(furniture) {
    this.furniture = furniture;
  }
}

let furniture = ['chair', 'TV', 'bed'];
let room = new Room(furniture);
console.log(room.furniture[1]); // 'TV'
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP wants to get furniture elements by indexing into `room`, not `room.furniture`.